# Difference between "!==" and "==!"

Tags: php, comparison, operators, comparison-operators

Yesterday I stumbled over this when I modified PHP code written by someone else. I was baffled that a simple comparison (`if ($var ==! " ")`) didn't work as expected. After some testing I realized that whoever wrote that code used `==!` instead of `!==` as comparison operator. I've never seen `==!` in any language so I wondered how the hell this code could even work and did some testing:

```
<?php
echo "int\n";
echo "1 !== 0: "; var_dump(1 !== 0);
echo "1 !== 1: "; var_dump(1 !== 1);
echo "1 ==! 0: "; var_dump(1 ==! 0);
echo "1 ==! 1: "; var_dump(1 ==! 1);
echo "bool\n";
echo "true !== false: "; var_dump(true !== false);
echo "true !== true: "; var_dump(true !== true);
echo "true ==! false: "; var_dump(true ==! false);
echo "true ==! true: "; var_dump(true ==! true);
echo "string\n";
echo '"a" !== " ": '; var_dump("a" !== " ");
echo '"a" !== "a": '; var_dump("a" !== "a");
echo '"a" ==! " ": '; var_dump("a" ==! " ");
echo '"a" ==! "a": '; var_dump("a" ==! "a");
?>
```

This produces this output:

```
int
1 !== 0: bool(true)
1 !== 1: bool(false)
1 ==! 0: bool(true)
1 ==! 1: bool(false)
bool
true !== false: bool(true)
true !== true: bool(false)
true ==! false: bool(true)
true ==! true: bool(false)
string
"a" !== " ": bool(true)
"a" !== "a": bool(false)
"a" ==! " ": bool(false)
"a" ==! "a": bool(false)
```

The operator seems to work for boolean and integer variables, but not for strings. I can't find `==!` in the PHP documentation or anything about it on any search engine (tried Google, Bing, DuckDuckGo, but I suspect they try to interpret it instead of searching for the literal string). Has anybody seen this before and can shed any light on this behavior?

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-this-operator

Comment: even more similar: [What is the difference between != and =! in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825840/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-java)

Comment: come on... what is with the upvotes? I can make a dozen more questions like this up. And accompany them by quasi serious analysis. This is standard textbook exercise practice, no. In SO, we vote for quality and information, not for fun and entertainment.

Comment: PS. I'm ***not*** saying the OP made this up (on purpose). I ***am*** saying SO is not achieving better content with voting patterns like this

Comment: This goes to show that a language-fixed amount of operators with greedy parsing can be just as problematic as the oh-so-"dangerous" allowing of custom-defined operators. In e.g. Haskell, the equivalent (misspelling the inequality `/=` as `=/`) would fail with a simple and concise error message: `Not in scope: '=/'`
    `Perhaps you meant one of these:`
      `'/' (imported from Prelude), '/=' (imported from Prelude),`
      `'==' (imported from Prelude)` — Though, thinking about it, the problem actually has more to do with having both infix and prefix operators.

Comment: @sehe He's getting upvotes because its the definition of a well researched question - he has "thouroughly searched for an answer", "been specific", the question is "relevant to others", and is "on topic".  the OP has tried things and shown us what he's tried; its the kind of question this site tries to foster

Comment: @JRaymond: he's getting upvotes because it's a trivia question for a very easy to understand problem and answer. The trivia aspect increases curiosity which drives more people in, and the easy aspect increases the percentage of those people who understand the question and the answer enough to vote on it. It is not related to it being a good question or not.

Comment: @AndreasBonini I would argue that they come for the trivia, they upvote for the quality of the question as posed - Lestways that's what I did, far be it from me to denigrate the motives of others.  At the least he doesn't deserve the downvotes.

Comment: @JRaymond, admit it, most of the high up-vote questions _are_ trivia. Take a look at these three questions of mine among many others: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11034689/912144), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9831567/912144), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7713459/912144). None of them are something you could just find on google (unlike most high up-vote questions) and they are well-thought and tried before being written (I know, because I wrote them). However, since they are questions that require expertise, they never get high votes. That's just how the system here works.

Comment: @JRaymond sehe is right. Writers would have a field-day on SO. I'd suggest going down this list (http://php.net/quickref.php) and coming up with interesting problems where the function is the solution. The more obscure and interesting the situation or function the more votes.

Comment: I've read somewhere that ==! processes slightly faster then !==. Nothing exponential, but really just comes down to the programmer's personal preference.

Comment: @MysteryMeatMonster have you actually read the answers here?

Answer (score 244, accepted):

The difference is that there is no operator `==!`.

This expression:

```
$a ==! $b
```

Is basically the same as this:

```
$a == (!$b)
```

Comment: Wow, a lot good answers in such a short time. I picked the first answer that clarified that the ! applies to the right hand variable and therefore has the most value. Sorry for the other guys ;)

Comment: @Gerald Schneider: The least you could do to make up for it was to improve this answer so that it was at least on par with the other answers in terms of grammar and formatting (one of which you specifically called out for its very detailed explanation!). But no matter, I've edited it now.

Comment: I don't even program in PHP and even I realized that "==!" would be read as the 2 operators "==" and "!". It just shows how much effect a little bit of layout can have on how you read something.

Comment: maybe because that you does not program in PHP so that you can say like this. PHP has operator `===` and `!==` which were not appeared on any other  languages (as far as I know).

Comment: @Bang Dao Um, JavaScript?  It has === and !==.  But no ==!

Comment: @psr http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp -> I didn't see operator `===` or `!==` was listed here.

Comment: @BangDao Now you found another reason for [w3fools](http://w3fools.com/) Please read it, it is important.

Answer (score 77):

## There is no `==!` operator in PHP

Its just a combination of `==` and `!`. Only relevant operator present here is `==`. So the combination `==!` will work just as a normal `==`, checking `Equality`, and trust me,

```
$variable_a ==! $variable_b
```

is none other than

```
$variable_a == (!$variable_b)
```

and thus;

```
"a" ==! " ": bool(false)
"a" ==! "a": bool(false) //is same as "a" == (!"a")
```

And

```
true ==! false: bool(true)
true ==! true: bool(false)
```

Combining multiple operators characters may not work as an operator always. for example, if we take `=` and `!`, it will work as operators only if it is in the pattern of `!=` or `!==`. There can be numerous combinations for these characters like  `!====`, `!==!` etc.. etc.. Operator combinations should be in **unique format**, **unique order**, **unique combinations** (all characters wont combine with all other characters) and definitely, **without any space between them**.

Check the operators list below;

[image]

Comment: I fell under the same illusion of being able to use a `<table>`.

Comment: + almost thought that was a table ... but its actually an image

Answer (score 39):

`==!` is not an operator but two :

`==` and `!`

`!` having a higher priority than `==`

So :

`"a" !== " ": bool(true)` --> true because "a" is really not equal to " "

`"a" ==! " ": bool(false)` --> false because "a" is not equals to !" "

Could be written with a space between == and !.

Comment: `false because "a" is not equals to !" "` !" " means cast to bool and negate that so " " is true and !" " is false.

Comment: @quarry Yes I didn't go too much inside the explanation :p

Answer (score 29):

`==!` doesn't exist as such. It's a somewhat cryptic notation of `== !`

As spaces don't matter in those operations, you could just as easily write `a --> b`, which evaluates to `a-- > b`, but will look strange.

So, as to the question: `"a" ==! " "` will be parsed to `"a" == !" "`. Negation of a string is covered by [casting](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.boolean.php), meaning any string but `"0"` and `" "` is, when casted, `true`.

Thus, the expression `"a" == !" "` will get transferred:

1. `"a" == !" "`
2. `"a" == !false`
3. `"a" == true`

And, as `string "a"` is not the same as `bool true`, this evaluates the whole expression to `false`.

So, what's the moral of the story? Don't let yourself be confused by missing or wrong placed spaces! :)

Comment: unlike stated in this answer, "a" == true evaluates to true because a not empty string is casted to the boolean value true. The expression "a" === true would evaluate to false.

Answer (score 25):

### ==! is not an operator

`==!` isn't a php comparison operator at all - it is the same as `== !` (note the space)

I.e.

```
if ("a" !== " ") {
    // evaluates to true - "a" and " " are not equal
}

if ("a" == !" ") {
    // unreachable
} else {
    // evaluates to false - "a" is not equal to true (!" " evaluates to true)
}
```